# Orbeon forms 2016.2 to 2016.2.1

Tags: orbeon

I am using orbeon forms 2016.2 professional edition right now and I plan to switch to 2016.2.1 because the release notes highly recommend for the upgrade. When I perform the switch,  can I use the same orbeon database that created with version  2016.2 without doing any patch works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data and table format hasn't changed between 2016.2 and 2016.2.1. (And in general, it shouldn't change in point releases, unless the change is really necessary to fix a bug.) So:

- If you are using a relational database, and have already upgraded it to the 2016.2 format, or created it with the 2016.2 DDL, you're good to go, and can just switch to 2016.2.1.
- If you're using the embedded eXist, you'll want to "copy" the `WEB-INF/exist-data` to the new version. For more on this, see point 2 in the [When using Form Builder and Form Runner](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/upgrading.html#when-using-form-builder-and-form-runner) section of the documentation.